# What does this line of code in Java mean?

Tags: java

My friend showed me his code for this project he's doing and one of the lines is this:

```
JFrame masterFrame =  (JFrame) Arrays.stream(JFrame.getFrames()).findFirst().get();
```

Evidently, the 'masterFrame' is now instantiated to be the first frame... the first in some sort of stream of frames. Also I understand that getFrames() returns an object of type frame and so that's why he's casting it as a JFrame.

Please if someone could help me out that would be great.
The project he's working on is an application that allows the user to select an image and then display it in a JFrame, and this masterFrame is the one that is resized and contains the image.

Comment: It looks like `getFrame()` returns an array of frames, and rather than getting the first element with `getFrame()[0]`, your friend is streaming the array and then taking the first element of the stream.

Comment: A simpler way to write this might be `(JFrame)JFrame.getFrames()[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.stream` creates a stream out of a `JFrame[]`, then `findFirst` and `get` are pretty self explanatory. basically this code is the same as.

```
JFrame masterFrame = JFrame.getFrames()[0];
```

with some stream things